# Extending $\sum_{n=0}^\infty s^{n^2}$ beyond its natural boundary

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-continuation, lacunary-series

Let $\mathbb{D} = \{s \in \mathbb{C} : |s| < 1\}$. Let $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where
$$ f(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^{n^2} $$
$f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$. This is what it looks like:
[image]
$\partial \mathbb{D}$ is a [natural boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Natural_boundary), so ordinary [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) cannot extend $f$ beyond $\mathbb{D}$. However, there might be another way to extend $f$ beyond $\mathbb{D}$ that is both aesthetically natural and yields a *unique* result. For example, see [generalized analytic continuation](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22generalized+analytic+continuation%22) and [*Continuation of functions beyond natural boundaries*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455514/continuation-of-functions-beyond-natural-boundaries).

Let
$$ \Delta = \left\{\exp \left( 2\pi i \frac{2n + 1}{4m + 2} \right) : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \subseteq \partial \mathbb{D} $$
Note that $\Delta$ is [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set). It seems that
\begin{align}
    \lim_{\substack{s \rightarrow \omega \\ s \in \mathbb{D}}} f(s) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
    \lim_{r \uparrow 1} \partial_r f(r \omega) &= 0
\end{align}
for all $\omega \in \Delta$. I have 2 questions:

1. Are there other $\omega \in \partial \mathbb{D} \setminus \Delta$ for which the above limits exist?
2. Is there an analytic (or meromorphic) $g : \mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that
   \begin{align}
       \lim_{\substack{s \rightarrow \omega \\ s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}}} g(s) &= \lim_{\substack{s \rightarrow \omega \\ s \in \mathbb{D}}} f(s) \\
       \lim_{r \downarrow 1} \partial_r g(r \omega) &= \lim_{r \uparrow 1} \partial_r f(r \omega)
   \end{align}
   for all $\omega \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ such that both sides are defined, and such that the LHS is undefined iff the RHS is undefined? That is, such that $g$ “matches” $f$ along $\partial \mathbb{D}$, in some sense?
   If so, is it unique? If not, are there additional conditions, perhaps some analogue of the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), that can give us a unique extension?

Comment: Not sure why are you asking this, which is *not* natural. $\theta(z)=\sum_n e^{2i\pi n^2 z}$ for $\Im(z)>0$. Do you like the extension $\theta(\overline{z})=\overline{\theta(z)}$ ? It is analytic on the lower half plane and we have $\lim_{y\to 0^+} \theta(x-iy)=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \overline{\theta(x+iy)}$ (where it converges, more generally in the sense of distributions). Note that the obtained function is even. If instead you set $\theta(\overline{z})=\theta(z)$ then it will be anti-holomorphic on the lower half-plane and it will have the same limiting distribution as $\theta(z)$.

Comment: The even extension is compatible with the natural extension of the RHS of $\theta(z)^4=\frac{-1}{\pi^2}(G_2(z)-4G_2(4z))=\frac{-1}{\pi^2}\sum_n\sum_{m,\ (n,m)\ne (0,0)} (\frac{1}{(nz+m)^2}-4\frac{1_{4|n}}{(nz+m)^2})$ so it should fit with a generalized version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3560260/276986).

Comment: the radial limits are $1/2$ at all points in $S$ so I am not sure what would be a reasonable answer beyond using $\theta$ function theory;

Comment: There are uncountable  analytic  functions on the unit disc with radial limits $1/2$ in $S$ and no radial limits at least on a set of full measure since $S$ is countable hence of Baire category 1 and we can get it included in a category 1 set of full measure and for category 1 sets the radial behavior  of analytic functions is equivalent to radial behavior of continuous functions, while it is easy to see that we can get continuous functions with radial limits $1/2$ in $S$ and fairly arbitrary (in particular no other radial limits in various ways) anywhere else

Comment: The general result (for any continuous function $\phi$ in the unit disc and any category 1 set $E$ on the unit circle there is an analytic function $f$ on unit disc st $f(re^{it})-\phi(re^{it}) \to 0, r \to 1, e^{it} \in E$) involves Mergelyan's approximation theorem so it is far from explicit and of course while one can make $E$ of full measure, it is still "small" in a sense so it is conceivable that such an $f$ would have radial limit points elsewhere in the complement, but for continuous $\phi$ that go radially to $1/2$ on $S$ and highly oscillate everywhere else, that seems unlikely

Comment: The first and more natural try that comes to my mind is the following function: $$ f(s) = \begin{cases} \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^{n^2} & s\in \Bbb D\\  \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^{-n^2} & s \in \Bbb C \setminus\overline{\Bbb D} \end{cases} $$ Then I'll try some sort of interpolation between the two branches of this functions. However, these are only thoughts.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri That does seem like a good candidate. I wonder whether it satisfies some kind of uniqueness property?

Comment: @user76284 probably no, it is not unique. The only “interesting” property is that the two representations of  the function inside and outside $\Bbb D$ coincide on the "cut" $\partial\Bbb D$ when their boundary limits are defined. However, ai I said before, these are only free thoughts.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri What I mean is whether it is unique in satisfying the "matching" criterion along $\partial \mathbb{D}$, along with being well-behaved/analytic/etc., since that would make it the canonical choice for "completing" $f$.

Comment: I thought a little bit of the problem. Perhaps uniqueness comes as a consequence of the Laurent series expansion in $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb D$: therefore you may have a  holomorphic function defined on $\Bbb D \cup (\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb D)$. However, it remain to check if the structure of this function shed some light on the problem you are analyzing.

Comment: I was able to rewrite it somewhat okay $ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (c)^{-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{ln(c)}}-1/2+\frac{ \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\ln(c)}}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-\pi^2 x^2}{\ln(c)}}.$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700299/a-ramanujan-like-summation-is-it-correct-is-it-extensible/3859675#3859675

Comment: Perhaps the q&a at this entry in MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198665/on-an-example-of-an-eventually-oscillating-function/198871 give well interesting related information.

Comment: @Conrad What about matching non-tangential limits, rather than just radial limits? Is uniqueness guaranteed then?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm a month late, but I wanted to go further with something Daniele mentioned in the comments. I've been considering something similar for a while, and I think the Laurent strategy Daniele mentioned is close to what I view as the correct answer is.

First, let's look at how something similar to the Laurent series can be used to analytically continue some of the more commonly seen functions. For instance, if we wished to continue
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$$
We could simply use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{-(-1)}x^n = Li_{-1}(x)$, and Li is defined for all x values. We can extend this to finite sums of powers of n, so we could see that
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+3n^2-n^3)x^n = Li_{-1}(x) + 3Li_{-2}(x)-Li_{-3}(x)$$
But, why have I introduced logarithmic integrals in relatively simple problems? Logorithmic integrals happen to have an incredibly fortunate method for continuation, which his that, for $|x|>1$,
$$Li_{-k}(x)=(-1)^{1+k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^kx^{-n}$$
This tells us that for the previous problems, we could have done
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+3n^2-n^3)x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^n$$
can be continued to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{-n}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^{-n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3x^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n-3n^{2}-n^{3}\right)x^{-n}$$
when |x|>1, and when |x|<1 we can use the regular sum. This fact allows us to gain a power and easy way to extend functions of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)x^n$ which have power series for f(n).
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^nb_kn^k $$
if one allows blindly interchanging the summations
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^nn^k =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k(-1)^{1+k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n}n^k = -f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k(-n)^k = -f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{-n}f(-n)$$
Then this method gives us a powerful method to continue functions which have a 'natural' power series, but struggles with the fact that $f(n)$ doesn't carry enough information to uniquely define a power series.

In particular, for this question, one possible valid definition for $f(n)$ is
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(x\right)\right)}{\pi\left(x\right)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(x-k^{2}\right)\right)}{\pi\left(x-k^{2}\right)}+\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(x+k^{2}\right)\right)}{\pi\left(x+k^{2}\right)}\right)$$
which corresponds to what Daniele got, since $f(n) = f(-n)$, and so this is one reason why Daniele's method happened to get something that works well.

I think there is at least a few reasons to prefer something like this for continuing this gap series. For one, it sort of generalizes square numbers. Since
$$\> 2 \quad 2 \quad 2 \quad 2 \quad 2 $$
$$\>\>\>\> \text{-}5 \quad \text{-}3 \quad \text{-}1 \quad 1 \quad 3 \quad 5 \quad$$
$$\text{ }9 \quad \text{ }4 \quad \text{ }1 \quad \text{ }0 \quad \text{ }1 \quad \text{ }4 \quad 9$$
seems to suggest that an extension of squared numbers should be even, whereas doing the same process of $n^3$ gives negatives on one side, and positive on the other, which suggests it should be odd. Indeed, choosing $f(n)$ is even when $n^k$ is even, and $f(n)$ is odd when $n^k$ is even produces continuous extensions, while doing it the opposite way does not.

Further, one can show that the two functions, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{(n^2)} \text{ and } \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{(-n^2)}$$ have derivatives that are all zero and agree at -1 by applying some regularizations to allow the functions to converge all the way up -1. The functions also just seem to mesh together in a natural way: [image]

I think this is only a first step, though, since the uniqueness problem is not addressed in any rigorous fashion--but I think they're some good reasons to think this is a good option for being the correct continuation. Let me know if you guys have any ideas on this.

Comment: A nice gem here !